# C++ to VBA (Excel)

Tags: c++, c, vba, excel

So, basically, in Excel, I have 4 columns of data (all with strings) that I want to process, and want to have the results in another column, like this (nevermind the square brackets, they just represent cells):

```
Line    Column1     Column2     Column3     Column4     Result
1:      [a]         [b]         [k]         [YES]       [NO]
2:      [a]         [c]         [l]         [YES]       [NO]
3:      [b]         [e]         []          [YES]       [NO]
4:      [c]         [e]         [f]         [NO]        [NO]
5:      [d]         [h]         [b]         [NO]        [NO]
6:      [d]         []          [w]         [NO]        [NO]
7:      [e]         []          []          [YES]       [NO]
8:      [j]         [m]         []          [YES]       [YES]
9:      [j]         []          []          [YES]       [YES]
10:     []          []          []          [YES]       [YES]
```

The process that I want the data to go through is this:

Assume that CheckingLine is the Line for which I currently want to calculate the value of Result, and that CurrentLine is any Line (except CheckingLine) that I am using to calculate the value of Result, at a given moment.

1. If Column4[CheckingLine] is "NO", Result is "NO" (simple enough, no help needed);

   1. Example: CheckingLine = 1 -> Column4[1] = "NO" -> Result = "NO";
2. Else, I want to make sure that all Lines that share a common value with CheckingLine (in any Column between 1 and 3), also have Column4 as "YES" (Doing that would be simple enough even without VBA - in fact, I started by doing it in plain Excel and realised that it wasn't what I wanted) - if that happens, Result is "YES";

   1. Example: CheckingLine = 8 -> Only shared value is "j" -> CurrentLine = 9 -> Column4[9] = "YES" -> Result = "YES";
   2. Here's the tricky part: If one of those lines has any value (again, in any Column between 1 and 3) that IS NOT shared with CheckingLine, I want to do the whole process (restart at 1.), but checking the CurrentLine instead.

      1. Example: CheckingLine = 2, "a" is shared with Line 1, c is shared with Line 4 -> CurrentLine = 1 -> Column4[1] = "YES", but "b" and "k" are not shared with CheckingLine -> CheckingLine' = 1 -> "b" is shared with Line 5 -> Column4[5] = "NO" -> Result = "NO";

I have written the corresponding C++ code (which works) (and it could have been in any other language, C++ was just the one I was using at the moment) (and the code HAS NOT been optimized in any way, because it's purpose was to be AS CLEAR about its functionality AS POSSIBLE) (the table above is the actual result of running it):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> column1, column2, column3, column4, contentVector;
unsigned int location, columnsSize;

void InsertInVector(std::string Content)
{
    if(Content == "")
    {
        return;
    }

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < contentVector.size(); i++)
    {
        if(contentVector[i] == Content)
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    contentVector.push_back(Content);
}

std::string VerifyCurrentVector(unsigned int Start)
{
    std::string result = "";

    if(contentVector.size() == 0)
    {
        result = "YES";
    }
    else
    {
        unsigned int nextStart = contentVector.size();

        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < columnsSize; i++)
        {
            if(i != location)
            {
                for(unsigned int j = Start; j < nextStart; j++)
                {
                    if(column1[i] == contentVector[j])
                    {
                        InsertInVector(column2[i]);
                        InsertInVector(column3[i]);
                    }
                    else if(column2[i] == contentVector[j])
                    {
                        InsertInVector(column1[i]);
                        InsertInVector(column3[i]);
                    }
                    else if(column3[i] == contentVector[j])
                    {
                        InsertInVector(column1[i]);
                        InsertInVector(column2[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if(nextStart == contentVector.size())
        {
            for(unsigned int i = 0; i < columnsSize; i++)
            {
                if(i != location)
                {
                    for(unsigned int j = 0; j < nextStart; j++)
                    {
                        if(column1[i] == contentVector[j] || column2[i] ==
                           contentVector[j] || column3[i] == contentVector[j])
                        {
                            if(column4[i] == "NO")
                            {
                                result = "NO";
                                return result;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            result = "YES";
        }
        else
        {
            result = VerifyCurrentVector(nextStart);
        }
    }

    return result;
}

std::string VerifyCell(unsigned int Location)
{
    std::string result = "";
    location = Location - 1;

    if(column4.size() < Location)
    {
        result = "Error";
    }
    else if(column4[location] == "NO")
    {
        result = "NO";
    }
    else
    {
        contentVector.clear();

        InsertInVector(column1[location]);
        InsertInVector(column2[location]);
        InsertInVector(column3[location]);

        result = VerifyCurrentVector(0);
    }

    return result;
}

void SetUpColumns(std::vector<std::string> &Column1, std::vector<std::string> &Column2,
                   std::vector<std::string> &Column3, std::vector<std::string> &Column4)
{
    if(Column4.size() > Column1.size())
    {
        for(unsigned int i = Column1.size(); i < Column4.size(); i++)
        {
            Column1.push_back("");
        }
    }
    if(Column4.size() > Column2.size())
    {
        for(unsigned int i = Column2.size(); i < Column4.size(); i++)
        {
            Column2.push_back("");
        }
    }
    if(Column4.size() > Column3.size())
    {
        for(unsigned int i = Column3.size(); i < Column4.size(); i++)
        {
            Column3.push_back("");
        }
    }

    column1 = Column1;
    column2 = Column2;
    column3 = Column3;
    column4 = Column4;
    columnsSize = Column4.size();
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4;

    Column1.push_back("a");
    Column1.push_back("a");
    Column1.push_back("b");
    Column1.push_back("c");
    Column1.push_back("d");
    Column1.push_back("d");
    Column1.push_back("e");
    Column1.push_back("j");
    Column1.push_back("j");

    Column2.push_back("b");
    Column2.push_back("c");
    Column2.push_back("e");
    Column2.push_back("e");
    Column2.push_back("h");
    Column2.push_back("");
    Column2.push_back("");
    Column2.push_back("m");

    Column3.push_back("k");
    Column3.push_back("l");
    Column3.push_back("");
    Column3.push_back("f");
    Column3.push_back("b");
    Column3.push_back("w");

    Column4.push_back("YES");
    Column4.push_back("YES");
    Column4.push_back("YES");
    Column4.push_back("NO");
    Column4.push_back("NO");
    Column4.push_back("NO");
    Column4.push_back("YES");
    Column4.push_back("YES");
    Column4.push_back("YES");
    Column4.push_back("YES");

    SetUpColumns(Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4);
    std::cout << "Line\t" << "Column1\t" << "Column2\t" << "Column3\t" << "Column4\t" <<
        std::endl;

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < Column4.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << i + 1 << ":\t" << "[" << column1[i] << "]\t[" << column2[i] <<
            "]\t[" << column3[i] << "]\t[" << column4[i] << "]\t[" << VerifyCell(i + 1)
            << "]" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So, after this lengthy explanation, what I want to know is this:

- Is there any way to do this in Excel's VBA (or even better, in plain Excel without VBA)?
- If not, how can I have my code (which I can easily translate to another C-like language and/or optimise) get the data from, and deliver the results to, Excel?

Comment: Just a couple comments, I don't think your question helps the greater community, pseudocode would probably have been equally useful to C++ code and I'm hoping this isn't a homework assignment. You have provided a very detailed question and if you're actually trying to get something done (and maybe learn in the process) then I'm happy to help. Next time maybe try to identify more specifically where you got stuck...

Comment: Using global variables is not recommended (unless sometimes you're doing old-school embedded systems). For the most part when using a global variable, what you really want is a parameter by-reference.

Comment: Also, especially when you're working with others (and for your own sanity) try not to use the same name on two different variables, and do try to comment your code. At least one line per function, so that others (or yourself later) do not need to decode your thoughts.

Comment: You claim "I have written the corresponding C++ code", I'm curious where did you learn to program C++ and what is the purpose of this effort?

Comment: @jason-k No, it is not homework, just trying to organize my own stuff. :)
I got stuck at the point where I I have only touched VBA once in my life and ran away from it, so I don't really know if there is a way to do what I asked: either translating this process to Excel/VBA, or have Excel use a C/C++/C# piece of code.
I also noted that I had no optimisations, which was a lazy way of saying that I whipped the code in a rush and only bothered to check if it was working or not - obviously, IF I end up using a C-like implementation instead of doing it in VBA, I'll have to improve it (A LOT).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to do this in Excel's VBA?

Yes, you can surely do this with VBA, it is a complete and powerful programming language

> (or even better, in plain Excel without VBA)?

Nope. The calculation seems too complicated to fit with Excel formulae without any VBA code.

> If not, how can I have my code (which I can easily translate to another C-like language and/or optimise) get the data from, and deliver the results to, Excel?

You can access Excel from C++ in many ways. Using ATL is one of them. another, easier way would be to import/export your Excel file in CSV format, which is easy to parse and write from C++.
Also consider C#, it has complete COM inter-operability to access office components.

Comment: @a-s-h After reading your answer, I searched for the C#-COM implementation and found a nice guide (even covers C++): http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/555660/Extend-your-VBA-code-with-Csharp-VB-NET-or-Cpluspl

Comment: @MikeAscended Thanks for sharing. To be honest, I never liked to use any methods of interfacing C++ with COM. Since the days of ATL, I was so discouraged that I dropped this option and did not try again with CLI. I do a lot of moving things from Excel to C++ back and forth, but I am very happy with using CVS format and linking Excel files to C++ results. With C# things are different of course. Anyway, it is a matter of personal taste. Good luck :)

Comment: I was going to try to offer an answer with plain VBA, I never finished mentally parsing the logic... I wouldn't mind an explanation of what the recursive VerifyCurrentVector() is doing.

Comment: @jason-k I broke down that function in two parts: 1, add shared cell values to a vector, while there are still some shared values between some two lines, and the second part, where when there are no more shared values, it checks to see if their "owners" have a "YES". The recursion is just so that, when looking for shared values in a line, it doesn't check for all the values already in the array, just those added in the previous iteration...

Comment: @jason-k ...(and YES, I know, it could/should have been much cleaner and more efficient, but as I said in my previous comment, this is just for my own personal use and I wasn't worried with optimisation/aesthetics/etc. - btw, since you asked before, I had to learn/have been learning C/C++/C# on my own)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if you like to "whipped the code in a rush" then you'll love VBA, next time please try to ask a more specific question. Based on code and comments @MikeAscended you're a relatively good programmer, with a grasp of functions/recursion, variable/parameters, conditions, loops, data structures, etc. Re: " I have only touched VBA once in my life and ran away from it" My intent is to get you started and give you syntax here not necessarily a working solution. I'm happy to answer any further specific questions you may continue to have.

**Strategy-wise**,
I recommend plain VBA which is easy to use in Excel. Obviously your problem can be solved in many ways including formulas, however VBA is a powerful tool that any programmer will benefit from using.

**Code-wise**,
To start access the editor from Excel press [Alt-F11], or from Design Mode insert and double-click an ActiveX button. To run a macro press [Alt-F8], or in VBA click the green play button.

One last note, if you want those line numbers in column 1 in excel then yours will become Column 2-5 or B-F. I'm assuming you'll use the row numbers in excel so that Column 1 is A, but row 1 will still have titles, so you are staring your data on row 2.

```
sub processResults_Col5()
' Run This Script as Main()
  dim rowCount as long, i as long 'rowCount  = columnsSize

with sheets(1)
  .Range("A1:D1") = Array("a", "b", "k", "YES")
  ' finish init here
  ' SetUpColumns not necessary in excel

if .cells(2,1).value <> "" then 'do not use .end(xldown) if data is missing
  rowCount = .cells(1,1).end(xldown).row

  for i = 1 to rowCount
    .cells(i,5) = verifyCell(i + 1, rowCount)
  next i

endif 'space will be added :p
end with
end sub

function  verifyCell(rowLocation as long, size as long, optional wSh as excel.worksheet) as string
' the rest should be easy for you to figure out based on C-code
with wSh 
if wsh is nothing then set wsh = activesheet 'let VBA capitalize stuff so you know you typed it correctly
if size < rowlocation then
    verifyCell = "Error" 'the function name is the return value
    'msgbox "Error" ' you can uncomment this line to see error
  elseif cells(rowLocation, 4).value = "NO" then
    cells(rowLocation, 5) = "NO" 'set result
  else
    call InsertInVector(rowLocation) 'CheckingLine
    ' edit the current rowLocation with for loops
    verifyCell = VerifyCurrentVector(0) 'whatever you're doing here
  endif
end with
end function
sub InsertInVector()
end sub
sub VerifyCurrentVector() 'function returns a value
end sub
```

Some tips:

1. Generally, Comment Your Code!
2. Generally, The first word/acronym of Variable and Object names should start in lowercase, then continue in camel-case. This helps distinguish them from library types.
3. In VBA always put [option explicit] in the beginning of every sheet/module, this requires you to [dim varName as Type] which will help debugging and make your code more explicit so it's easy to understand.
4. In VBA for numbers use type Long, learn early vs late-binding. If you're instantiating any object that requires a reference/library, always state it explicitly. This includes Excel.Worksheet, Excel.Workbook, etc. (eg. you may want your code in MS Access)
5. In Office One of the first settings you're going to want to disable is the popup error window, also use debug.print and the immediate box a few times.
6. Generally, as you know from C++ take your time, try to write correct code on your the first try as this will save you debugging time. Try not to rush and keep coffee & healthy snacks on hand. Good luck and have fun :)